# Complex Listview like in google currents

Tags: android, listview

I would like to create a complex listview like what can be seen in google currents :

[image]
<sub>(source: [mshcdn.com](http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEyLzEyLzEyLzBhL2dvb2dsZWN1cnJlLmtNSS5wbmc/a3d1eaa2/8ea/google-currents-headsup2.png))</sub>

I was first thinking that a webview would do the trick but since there is an animation on each element inserted, it's probably really a list view. So my question is how can this be achieved (ie doing a render of each row with a different layout (no viewholder for preventing layout inflating?) and managing async loading and resizing of big images in a very large smooth vertical list)?

Comment: you should try it first and then post a specific question. The way it is now it looks like you want someone else to do all the hard working for you. Also, you have an update on your phone, you should update your phone.

Comment: This can be achieved by adding additional code to the ListView class by creating your own class extending the ListView class.

Comment: Budius > I'm not interested in someone doing it for me. What's the point ? I just would like to know if ListView is really the way to do and if there's some things I should be careful about.

Comment: Hey dude (@user1102206), you got an answer to your question?